# Landing council members

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Why is it, when I decide to land a council member in order to boost their opinion, do I end up losing them? If I give, say, my spymaster a minor barony that I own, they are still my direct vassal, but I end up losing them, which defeats the whole point of landing them in the first place. I can appoint, say, a mayor as spymaster, so why can't I make my spymaster a mayor? What exactly are the rules here?

Comment: @Philipp: I'll give you that it's a dupe of that question, but that question doesn't really seem to have a very solid and authoritative answer either.

Comment: If you're asking why PDX made the game this way, we can't help you. We're not PDX.

Comment: @Studoku: No that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how to land a councilor without losing them. What are the rules regarding councilors and landing. Now it seems if you wait a bit you should be able to rehire them, but it seems there might also be restrictions based on what title you gave them. For example, if you make your court chaplain a baron, you won't be able to take them back as chaplain (from what I understand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving away a title causes the character to leave your court. If they leave your court, they are no longer on your council.

If they are still your direct vassal and still eligible for the position (landed non-priests cannot be chaplain for example), wait a few days. They will become available again.

Comment: So giving somebody some land (while still being your direct vassal) does cause them to leave for *some period of time* and then come back? That's still marginally annoying.

Comment: @Wjousts They only come back if you manually give them the job again. I can't speculate on why PDX made it this way but it does give you a way to dismiss a councillor without upsetting them.